# Cannot add a redis cartridge on openshift

Tags: openshift

We are trying to add redis cartridge to Openshift, we got the following after trying to add redis cartridge to Openshift.

**Code**

```
rhc add-cartridge http://cartreflect-claytondev.rhcloud.com/reflect\?github\=smarterclayton/openshift-redis-cart -a <appname>
```

**Error**

```
The cartridge  to application '<appname>' ... 
Unexpected error: User does not exist in cgroups: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Is the application you are trying to add it to in another namespace (domain)? if so you need to use the -n option.